# react-i18next Trans component interpolation with bold tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, i18next, react-i18next

Upon upgrading my react-i18next versions I noticed my previously working code now has an intellisense error:

```
import { Trans } from 'react-i18next';

  <Trans i18nKey="myComponent.notify">
      Notification sent to <b>{{ name: name}}'s</b>
  </Trans>
```

`Error: Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.`

If I run the code it works fine, so this is an intellisense issue. However I noticed if I remove the `<b>` tags, the intellisense issue disappears.

How can I make my intellisense work without removing my `<b>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by implementing a i18next.d.ts

https://www.i18next.com/overview/typescript

import 'i18next';

```
declare module 'i18next' {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    allowObjectInHTMLChildren: true;
  }
}
```